# Table cannot locate itself properly inside the document

Tags: tables, spacing

Sometimes, table cannot locate itself properly inside my document and I don't know how to fix this.

Here is an example:

The current page which the table cannot locate itself properly in looks like as follows:

[image]

As you can see, there is too much space in between.

The previous and next pages look like this (left one is previous and the right one is the next page):

[image] [image]

The `documentclass` is book and the table code is as follows:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ p{4cm} p{5cm}  p{6cm} }
%\hline
\cellcolor[gray]{0.9} Foo1 Title & \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}Foo2 Title & \cellcolor[gray]{0.9} Foo3 Title \\ \hline
Foo & Foo & Foo Bar bla bla bla...\\
Foo & Foo & Foo Bar bla bla bla...\\[5pt]

\hline
\end{tabular}

Table xxx: Foo Caption 
\end{center}
```

Figures can do this very properly. If the space is not enough inside the page, then the image puts itself in the next page but the space in the current page filled with text or something else.

Any idea how can I can fix this problem so that tables can locate themselves properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your `figure` environments behave the way you describe is that they are floats. The `tabular` environment is *not* a float.

To achieve the desired behaviour, you should wrap your `tabular` environments within the `table` environment, which *does* float.

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Table caption goes here}
\begin{tabular}
...
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Note that I've used `\centering` and *not* `\begin{center}...\end{center}` which adds extra vertical space.

You can change the `htbp` to suit your desired placement of floats. For further reading, have a look at

- [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020#39020)
- [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables)

Comment: I am having one other problem with this one: I have also `lstlisting` blocks and they can sometimes go into two pages. If I follow the above style that u have suggested, table goes inside the lstlisting block if the `listing` block occupies two pages. Any chance I can fix this?

Comment: @tugberk that's really a separate question :) however, the `placeins` package provides the command `\FloatBarrier` which you could put before your `lstlisting` environments